# Extract a function-call expression's arguments with names

Tags: r, rlang

Let's say I have an expression representing a function call, where some arguments are named and some are positional.

```r
expr <- quote(mean(1:5, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Would it be possible to extract the arguments and all of their names?

```r
magic_function(expr)
#> $x
#> 1:5
#> 
#> $na.rm
#> TRUE
```

Obviously this would be impossible if some of the positional arguments fall into `...`. However, I'm interested in cases where the names of positional arguments could be extracted from the formals.

The `rlang` package has `call_args()` which comes close, but it doesn't give the name of the positional arguments.

```r
rlang::call_args(expr)
#> [[1]]
#> 1:5
#> 
#> $na.rm
#> [1] TRUE
```

I thought of a wrapper around `call_args` which compares its argument names with those obtained by `fn_fmls_names`, gets the difference and then sets the missing argument names. This would work but feels a bit messy. Also, it wouldn't work with generics.

For a truer-to-life example demonstrating the issue with generics, let's say my expression is actually

```r
expr <- quote(DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:"))
```

`DBI::dbConnect` has two standard arguments: `drv` for the driver object and `...` for any necessary setup arguments. However, the [RSQLite method for `dbConnect`](https://github.com/r-dbi/RSQLite/blob/main/R/dbConnect_SQLiteDriver.R) has many more arguments, such as `dbname` (to which `":memory:"` is assigned).

So my hope would be to have some sort of `magic_function(expr)` which outputs

```r
#> $drv
#> RSQLite:SQLite()  # or something...

#> $dbname
#> ":memory:"
```

So, is it possible to get something similar, but detecting that the positional argument in the `mean()` example is `x = 1:5` more elegantly? And for extra brownie points, this would also have to somehow handle generics like the `dbConnect()` example!

---

<sub>Given R is lazily evaluated, I wouldn't be surprised if this isn't possible (probably method selection from generics is only done once the generic is actually evaluated, not when it's merely quoted), but I haven't really gotten my head around how this evaluation works under the hood.</sub>

Comment: Are you looking for formalArgs(def = your_function) ? However, it will only work for functions and won't tell you default values.

Comment: formals(your_function) would tell you arguments and default values. However, it still only works with functions

Comment: @LevonIpdjian: Not quite. `formalArgs()` gives me a string vector with the names of all function arguments. I'm looking for a function which gives me a named list of arguments actually used in a call, including positionals by name (i.e. `formalArgs(mean)` gives me `"x" "..."`, but I want `magic_function(mean(1:5))` which gives me `$x 1:5`). And preferably a method which also works with generics.

Comment: @akrun: That why I mentioned generics. I'd love a solution which can actually evaluate the actual method called. So basically, that `magic_function(mean(1:5))` would be equivalent to `magic_function(mean.default(1:5))`.

Answer (score 2):

The generic case harder.  First, here's the simple case:

```r
expr <- quote(mean(1:5, na.rm = TRUE))

fn <- expr[[1]]
match.call(eval(fn), expr)
#> mean(x = 1:5, na.rm = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1.9000)</sup>

To do the generic, you'd need to know that the generic doesn't call anything except `UseMethod`, then figure out which method it would call, and do something like this:

```r
expr <- quote(mean(1:5, 0, na.rm = TRUE))

generic <- as.character(expr[[1]])
arg1 <- expr[[2]]
class <- class(eval(arg1))

method <- getS3method(generic, class, optional = TRUE)
if (is.null(method))
  method <- getS3method(generic, "default")

match.call(method, expr)
#> mean(x = 1:5, trim = 0, na.rm = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1.9000)</sup>

EDITED to ADD:

You've expanded your question.  The simple case above will still work, but you'll need lots more work on the generic example.  Finding the name of the generic in `DBI::dbConnect` is harder.  It's also more obvious that evaluating the first argument to find its class is undesirable:  you probably don't want to call `RSQLite::SQLite()` during your analysis and again later if you evaluate `expr`.

ANOTHER EDIT:

`DBI::dbConnect` is an S4 generic, not an S3 generic.  So you'd need a completely different set of code to handle that.